# Console error models.load_fields is not a function while I try to load custom field into POS odoo16

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-15, odoo-16

This console error faced me when I try to use `models.load_fields` to load custom field to POS orderline:

[image: Console: 'TypeError: models.load_fields is not a function']

My code as follow:

```
odoo.define('serial_attributes.pos_attributes', function (require) {
    "use strict";
    console.log("Iam HEreeeeeeeeeeeeeee!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")

    var models = require("point_of_sale.models");
    var _super_orderline = models.Orderline.prototype;
    console.log("models", models);
    models.load_fields("product.product", "test")
    models.Orderline = models.Orderline.extend({
        initialize: function (attr, options) {
            var line = _super_orderline.initialize.apply(this, session, arguments);
            this.test = this.product.test;
            console.log("test", this.test)
        }
    })


})
```

I try to load custom field to porduct.product to show it with POS order.

Comment: Do you have any code extending `models.load_fields`?

Comment: nothing except this code in my custom module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odoo should raise:

```
ReferenceError: session is not defined
```

The session parameters passed to `apply` is not defined in this context, you should remove it

You don't need to assign the result to the `line` variable

You can find an example in [pos_restaurant](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/pos_restaurant/static/src/js/notes.js) module that extends the `OrderLine` to add a `note` field

***Original code:***

```
odoo.define('pos_restaurant.notes', function (require) {
"use strict";

var models = require('point_of_sale.models');

var _super_orderline = models.Orderline.prototype;
models.Orderline = models.Orderline.extend({
    initialize: function(attr, options) {
        _super_orderline.initialize.call(this,attr,options);
        this.note = this.note || "";
    },
    set_note: function(note){
        this.note = note;
        this.trigger('change',this);
    },
    get_note: function(note){
        return this.note;
    },
    can_be_merged_with: function(orderline) {
        if (orderline.get_note() !== this.get_note()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return _super_orderline.can_be_merged_with.apply(this,arguments);
        }
    },
    clone: function(){
        var orderline = _super_orderline.clone.call(this);
        orderline.note = this.note;
        return orderline;
    },
    export_as_JSON: function(){
        var json = _super_orderline.export_as_JSON.call(this);
        json.note = this.note;
        return json;
    },
    init_from_JSON: function(json){
        _super_orderline.init_from_JSON.apply(this,arguments);
        this.note = json.note;
    },
});
```

**For Odoo 16**

The Javascript framework has changed.

As you can read in the [[REF] point_of_sale,*pos*: remove Backbone.js, single loading request](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/8fb53c53c3128e8cea7ef20b9ab4946ac2f9b7d9)  commit:

It is possible to make customizations in the loading but is done in
several steps:

1. Override `_pos_ui_models_to_load` to include the new model to load.
2. Define `_loader_params_<model_name>` to define the `search_params` and
   optional `context`.
3. Define `_get_pos_ui_<model_name>` to return the data that will be
   included in the full `loaded_data`. Perform the organization in this method
   whenever necessary.
4. Override `_pos_data_process` for further post processing. The final
   form of `loaded_data` in this method will be sent to the frontend.
   To make customization
   To load a model, you need to use `_loader_params_MODEL_MODEL` in the `pos.session` model. You can find an example used to load [res_country](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/point_of_sale/models/pos_session.py#L1694) model. The [point_of_sale](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/point_of_sale/models/pos_session.py#L1873) already loads the product model so you need to override that function and extend the list of fields

***Example:***

```py
class PosSession(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'pos.session'

    def _loader_params_product_product(self):
        result = super()._loader_params_product_product()
        result['search_params']['fields'].extend(['test'])
        return result
```

To override `Orderline` use the following code

```py
odoo.define('serial_attributes.pos_attributes', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    const { Orderline } = require('point_of_sale.models');
    const Registries = require('point_of_sale.Registries');

    const PosAttributesOrderline = (Orderline) => class PosAttributesOrderline extends Orderline {
        constructor() {
            super(...arguments);
            this.test = this.product.test;
        }
    };

    Registries.Model.extend(Orderline, PosAttributesOrderline);
});
```

***Edit: Load a new model***

As an example, we can use the `pos_hr` module that overrides the POS session functions mentioned above and extends the POS widget to define the employee list

1/ Inherit `pos.session` model

```py
class PosSession(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'pos.session'

    def _pos_ui_models_to_load(self):
        result = super()._pos_ui_models_to_load()
        new_model = 'hr.employee'
        if new_model not in result:
            result.append(new_model)
        return result

    def _loader_params_hr_employee(self):
        return {'search_params': {'domain': [], 'fields': ['name', 'id', 'user_id'], 'load': False}}

    def _get_pos_ui_hr_employee(self, params):
        employees = self.env['hr.employee'].search_read(**params['search_params'])
        return employees

    def _pos_data_process(self, loaded_data):
        super()._pos_data_process(loaded_data)
        loaded_data['employee_by_id'] = {employee['id']: employee for employee in loaded_data['hr.employee']}
```

2/ Extend The POS widget to set the employees list

```
const { PosGlobalState } = require('point_of_sale.models');

const PosAttributesPosGlobalState = (PosGlobalState) => class PosAttributesPosGlobalState extends PosGlobalState {
    async _processData(loadedData) {
        await super._processData(...arguments);
        this.employee_by_id = loadedData['employee_by_id'];
    }
}

Registries.Model.extend(PosGlobalState, PosAttributesPosGlobalState);
```

To access the list of employees from the order line use: `this.pos.employee_by_id`

Comment: First, thanks for your interest. I did it and that is what I got                                               [Error while loading serial_attributes.models: models.Orderline.extend is not a function TypeError: models.Orderline.extend is not a function]

Comment: The above code is valid for Odoo 15. Are you using Odoo 16?

Comment: yes I'm using v16

Comment: Check my edit `For Odoo 16`

Comment: Its working now. Thank you what if I need to load models to pos instead field ?

Comment: As mentioned in the commit message, you need to override the `_pos_ui_models_to_load` function to include the new model to load

Comment: can you send me the exactly how should js file like ?

Comment: I am busy at the moment, but as soon as I can, I will provide an example

Comment: Thank you anyway, but please don't forget to provide only one simple example to show the difference as I'm in learning level .

Comment: I added an example to load the ``hr.employee`` model based on the `pos_hr` module